# How does Elasticsearch switch to another node in case the master node fails?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my production environment, I have a two-node cluster and each node sits on a different physical box. One node sits on a machine with IP being 172.21.0.21, and the other 172.21.0.22.

In my development environment (one laptop only), I have the following working Java code:

```
client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

Now I need to run my app in the production environment. Which IP address to use in my Java code to talk to ES (2.2.0)? How does my application switch to another node if the node it talks to fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to add all IP addresses you wish your client to connect to:

```
client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("172.21.0.21"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("172.21.0.22"), 9300));
```

If one of them fails, the client will try the others in the list and eventually connect back to the one that failed once it's back up.

Comment: Val, thanks for your input. The solution doesn't look pretty if I have to specify each node in the Java code. What if there is a new node? It would be nice if ES allows comma-separated multiple addresses in the code so that I can externalize this input.

Comment: You can definitely provide your own settings as a comma-separated list, then split it on commas and loop over each IPs and repeatedly call `addTransportAddress()` on each.

Comment: Val, thanks for the split and loop idea. I did use this approach in other places. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method in `TransportClient` class that takes list of `transport addresses`

```
public TransportClient addTransportAddresses(TransportAddress... transportAddress)
```

You can use that if you want.

Comment: Richa, thanks for your chiming in! Good to know this more elegant approach.

Comment: To add one more thing, `addTransportAddress` internally calls `addTransportAddresses`. You can see that in implementation.

Comment: Nice Richa, that still requires to parse the IP list and loop over them though to construct an array of `TransportAddress`.

Comment: Note that it doesn't call `TransportClient.addTransportAddresses` but the one from `TransportClientNodesService`

Comment: Richa, would you mind to update your post to show how it works correctly?